# VS 2010 c++ Express cannot link recv() and send()

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, express

I am running 64-bit Win 7 and using VS 2010 c++ Express.
I am trying to learn how to build a win32 app that can connect to a website.
When I build the app, I get the follow link error msgs:

```
1>  Generating Code...
1>PWP.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
     __imp__recv@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl PWP(struct HWND__ *,char *)" (?PrintWebPage@@YAHPAUHWND__@@PAD@Z)
1>PWP.obj : error LNK2019: .. __imp__send@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl PrintWebPage(struct HWND__ *,char *)" (?PrintWebPage@@YAHPAUHWND__@@PAD@Z)
1>PWP.obj : error LNK2019: .. __imp__closesocket@4 referenced in function "int __cdecl PrintWebPage(struct HWND__ *,char *)" (?PrintWebPage@@YAHPAUHWND__@@PAD@Z)
1>PWP.obj : error LNK2019: .. __imp__connect@12 referenced in function "int __cdecl PrintWebPage(struct HWND__ *,char *)" (?PrintWebPage@@YAHPAUHWND__@@PAD@Z)
1>PWP.obj : error LNK2019: .. __imp__htons@4 referenced in function "int __cdecl PrintWebPage(struct HWND__ *,char *)" (?PrintWebPage@@YAHPAUHWND__@@PAD@Z)
1>PWP.obj : error LNK2019: .. __imp__inet_addr@4 referenced in function "int __cdecl PrintWebPage(struct HWND__ *,char *)" (?PrintWebPage@@YAHPAUHWND__@@PAD@Z)
1>PWP.obj : error LNK2019: .. __imp__WSACleanup@0 referenced in function "int __cdecl PrintWebPage(struct HWND__ *,char *)" (?PrintWebPage@@YAHPAUHWND__@@PAD@Z)
1>PWP.obj : error LNK2019: .. __imp__WSAGetLastError@0 referenced in function "int __cdecl PrintWebPage(struct HWND__ *,char *)" (?PrintWebPage@@YAHPAUHWND__@@PAD@Z)
1>PWP.obj : error LNK2019: .. __imp__socket@12 referenced in function "int __cdecl PrintWebPage(struct HWND__ *,char *)" (?PrintWebPage@@YAHPAUHWND__@@PAD@Z)
1>PWP.obj : error LNK2019: .. __imp__WSAStartup@8 referenced in function "int __cdecl PrintWebPage(struct HWND__ *,char *)" (?PrintWebPage@@YAHPAUHWND__@@PAD@Z)
1>PWP.obj : error LNK2019: .. __imp__WSASetLastError@4 referenced in function _WspiapiGetAddrInfo@16
1>PWP.obj : error LNK2019: .. __imp__inet_ntoa@4 referenced in function _WspiapiLegacyGetAddrInfo@16
1>PWP.obj : error LNK2019: .. __imp__htonl@4 referenced in function _WspiapiLegacyGetAddrInfo@16
1>PWP.obj : error LNK2019: .. __imp__getservbyname@8 referenced in function _WspiapiLegacyGetAddrInfo@16
1>PWP.obj : error LNK2019: .. __imp__gethostbyname@4 referenced in function _WspiapiQueryDNS@24
1>PWP.obj : error LNK2019: .. __imp__gethostbyaddr@12 referenced in function _WspiapiLegacyGetNameInfo@28
1>PWP.obj : error LNK2019: .. __imp__getservbyport@8 referenced in function _WspiapiLegacyGetNameInfo@28
1>PWP.obj : error LNK2019: .. __imp__ntohs@4 referenced in function _WspiapiLegacyGetNameInfo@28
1>C:\Users\Robert\Documents\Rob\Apps4win\WebsiteComm\Debug\WebsiteComm.exe : fatal
```

Does VS 2010 c++ Express support these functions?
If so, how do I get my project to locate and link to them?

I believe these to be appropriate questions for this forum.
If not, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to link `wsock32.lib` in your project.

Comment: Problem resolved.  I added the SDK v7.1A lib directory under to the project lib directory list, and I am now able to compile and link the app (though it still doesn't work -- the next step on my learning curve).  Thank you for your assistance.